# Set title of an Android Item

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to set the title of an Android `Item`in the Java code. I know its possible in the xml file but I want to do it dynamically from within my Java Code. So this was my existing XML file:

```
 <item
     android:id="@+id/txn">
     android:title="@string/txn">
    <menu>
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/txn_item"
             />
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
```

So i want to remove the `android:title` field and do it direct in Java. So far im trying to do it as follows, but get a NPE:

```
MenuItem  txn_type_item = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.txn);
txn_type_item.setTitle("TESTING!");
```

Is `MenuItem` not the right object type here? Or is there something else I am doing wrong?

Comment: okay but when do you set this string to the element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code..

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    MenuItem item=menu.getItem(itemIndex); // here itemIndex is int
    item.setTitle("YourTitle");
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do your changes inside `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu)` and just call the `InvalidateOptionsMenu();` whehenever you want to change the title.